# Write multiple values to object array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a table with a list of entries that I need to sum the hours from. The entries need to be for each month by the user. I have grouped the entries by distinct user:

```
var entries = db.ARTCockpit_Global.ToList().Where(u => u.UserDepartmentShort == "TGUCU").GroupBy(x => x.UserName).Distinct();
```

I need to write an object array for each user by month, for example below Jan, Feb:

```
foreach (var user in entries)
{
    object[] value = new object[] { 5, 2 };
    allSeries.Add(new Series { Data = new Data(value), Name = user.First().UserName });
}
```

The problem with a foreach loop is that it will create an array for each value, e.g. [5],[2]

Database example extract:

```
Date        YYYYMM  Year    MM  DD  DDnum   UserID  UserName       Hours
2015-01-12  201501  2015    01  12  12      Milesdc Miles, Dean      5
2015-01-12  201501  2015    01  12  12      MMaslan Maslan, Martin   4
2015-02-05  201502  2015    02  05  5       Milesdc Miles, Dean      2
2015-02-05  201502  2015    02  05  5       MMaslan Maslan, Martin   8
```

Comment: What are you iterating over? I don't see how iterating over `value` will produce individual arrays

Comment: Sorry, iterating over the entries list. Then i need to get the sum hours for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that your table corresponds to `ARTCockpit_Global` object, alhough it does not have a `UserDepartmentShort` property. You can group the results with linQ and complete sum as :

```
var total = (from x in db
             group x by new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.UserId } into grp
             select new
             {
                 grp.Key.UserId,
                 grp.Key.Month,
                 grp.Key.Year,
                 Total = grp.Sum(x => x.Hours)
             }).ToList();
```